# MySQL Procedure - Insert row if not exists

Tags: mysql, sql

OK, this is what I want to do :

- If an entry already exists (e.g. based on field `name`), then just return its `id`
- If it doesn't, add it

This is what I've managed so far (for the "if doesn't exist, create it" part) :

```
INSERT INTO `objects` (`id`,`name`)
    SELECT NULL,'someObj2' FROM `objects`
        WHERE NOT EXISTS
             (SELECT name FROM `objects` WHERE `name`='someObj2');
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

How can I get the `id` (instead of `LAST_INSERT_ID()`) if the entry **does** exist?

---

P.S. Yep, I know that the main reason I can't get my head around SQL is the degree at which I'm used to the more classical if-then-else approach of regular programming languages... lol

---

**UPDATE :**

I keep trying and trying and this what I've managed so far (as a stored procedure) :

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `objects` WHERE `name` = NAME) 
THEN
    SELECT `id` FROM `objects` WHERE `name` = NAME;
ELSE
    INSERT INTO `objects` (`id`,`name`) VALUES(NULL,NAME);
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS 'id';
END IF
```

and calling it like: `CALL insertObject("someObj2");`

However, it's not working as expected - neither does it add the entry, nor does it return the id (instead it returns *all* `id`s in the table...). Any idea what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to enforce a `unique` constraint on `name`.  If so, you can also do this by just declaring the column to be `unique` or equivalently creating a unique index:

```
create unique index objects_name on objects(name);
```

If this is true, then change the question from getting the last inserted `id` to just getting the `id` for `name`:

```
select id
from objects o
where o.name = 'someObj2';
```

I hasten to add that in a high-transaction environment where things are being added and deleted quickly, any approach might have a problem.  Consider your code, the row could be inserted and then deleted, even before the `last_insert_id()` is executed.  If you are dealing with a high transaction environment with potential race conditions, then you need to use transactions and locking to do what you want.

Comment: Could you please have a look at the update in my original question?

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon . . . The problem with your code is that `NAME` the variable and `name` the column are the same.  When using parameters, it is a good idea to prefix them with something to avoid this type of conflict.  Try `v_name` for the variable.

Comment: OMG, SQL makes me feel stupid... lol. Yep, that was it! (Why did I imagine it *would* be case-sensitive?!) Thanks a lot, mate! :-)